# Getting an error as `should correctly return` while testing my service using `jasmine-marbles`

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine-marbles

I am getting an error as:

```
 TypeError: actual.subscribe is not a function

      19 |     it('should correctly return', () => {
      20 |         const expectedValues = cold('--a', {a:[]});
    > 21 |         expect(sut.getAvailabilityType).toBeObservable(expectedValues);
         |                                         ^
      22 |     })
      23 | })
```

But not able to understand the issue. here is my service snippet:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CandidateRegistrationManagementService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getAvailabilityType(): Observable<ModelAvailabilityType> {
        return this.http.get<ModelAvailabilityType>(environment.setUpAndConfigUrl + `LookupTypeValue/LookupValueTypeDetails?LookupTypeName=AvailabilityType`)
            .pipe(
                map(events => {
                    return events;
                }),
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }
```

})

here is my testing for the above service(get):

```
import { cold, hot } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { CandidateRegistrationManagementService } from './candidate-registration-management.service';


describe('new service', () => {
    let sut:CandidateRegistrationManagementService;
    let mockService:any;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockService = jasmine.createSpy('getAvailabilityType');
        mockService.getAvailabilityType = hot('^-a', {a:[]});
        sut = new CandidateRegistrationManagementService(mockService);
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(sut).toBeTruthy();
    })

    it('should correctly return', () => {
        const expectedValues = cold('--a', {a:[]});
        expect(sut.getAvailabilityType).toBeObservable(expectedValues);
    })
})
```

I am not able to understand the issue. any help me here?
I followed a tutorial from [Here](https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/how-i-write-marble-tests-for-rxjs-observables-in-angular/)

Comment: Maybe it should be `sut.getAvailabilityType()` instead of `sut.getAvailabilityType` ? `getAvailabilityType` seems to be a method which returns an observable and you're not invoking it.

Comment: @AndreiGătej - if I try like so, getting an error as `new service › should correctly return` and  `TypeError: this.http.get is not a function`  any clue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. What logs if you do `console.log(sut.getAvailabilityType())` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej - I am not consoled anything. even before getting an error as `TypeError: this.http.get is not a function` can you check my get function?

Comment: I think `mockService` from `new CandidateRegistrationManagementService(mockService)` should have a `get` method. Maybe add a spy on it

Comment: may be correct. how to add spy on it? is it not enough: `mockService = jasmine.createSpy('getAvailabilityType');` which i already declared

Comment: `spyOn(mockService, 'get').and.returnValue(of(...))`. https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217069/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-andrei-gtej).